# ToolStripStatusLabel is not displayed after the window be restored(after minimize)

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I have a simple StatusStrip with one ToolStripStatusLabel in it. Text in label can be quite long, so I have prefered to display it cutted.
I have set ToolStripStatusLabel properties: `Spring=true` and `TextAlign=MiddleLeft`. I didn't want to set StatusStrip's property `LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow`, because with `ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow` the Text will be overridden with triangle(for resizing).[image]

The Text property is set directly after `InitializeComonents()` and is displayed as expected - cutted.
If I do minimize(to  taskbar) and then restore the window, the text will not be displayed at all. If I make window wider I can see the text, and if I bring the window to the initial size I still can see the text, cutted as expected.

I have and will post my solution, but I would ask you, whether you have any elegant one?

Comment: StatusStrip has [known weirdo painting problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24379233/17034).  You can only get a useful answer if you post repro code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your response. I really don't know which code I have to post(designer code?), all things be needed to reproduce the issue I have pointed in the question. Just minimize the window with cutted label in strip and restore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is quite simple. Just handle the window's restore event(there is no such event, but there is a workaround:
[Is there an event raised in C# when a window is restored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594762/is-there-an-event-raised-in-c-sharp-when-a-window-is-restored)) and reset the text in ToolStripStatusLabel:

```
var txt = tslabel.Text;
tslabel.Text = " ";
tslabel.Text = txt;
```