# How to provide different border color for active and inactive state of a custom form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a custom form.

For that I have derived the class from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class and overridden the `WndProc(ref Message m)` method.

I have processed the `WM_NCPAINT` to draw the title bar, control buttons(close, minimize, maximize buttons), border and icon of the form.

I need to provide different border color for active and inactive state of the form.

For that I have used the below code.

```
private void DrawBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle rect)
    {
        var borderColor = this.ContainsFocus ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(borderColor), rect);
    }
```

This provide exact output when I place two forms(as in the below image) and switch from one form to another form by mouse click.
[image]

But the problem is when I minimize the form and restore it by clicking the form icon on the task bar, the form border was in inactive color(Color.Red).

I have tried to override the `OnActivated()` method and call `Refresh()` or `UpdateStyles()` method in it. But this doesn't provide any result.

Please suggest me a way to achieve my requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594762/is-there-an-event-raised-in-c-sharp-when-a-window-is-restored

Comment: Thanks for the response. Got solution.